# R: find value >0 and check the sum of two consecutive values in a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns: year and area (whole numbers).

```
df<-data.frame(year = 1:7,
           area = c(5,0,0,8,0,8,4))

  year area
1    1    5
2    2    0
3    3    0
4    4    8
5    5    0
6    6    8
7    7    4
```

I would like to:

- Find the first year with area > 0
- If found, check the sum of
  area in two consecutive years. If the sum >0, print the year of the value. Else, (if the sum =0), search for following number in a vector.

So, in this case, year #1 has area 5. But, the sum of area of two following years (#2 and #3) is 0. Therefore, I need to inspect the new year in the dataframe with area >0, which is year #4. Again, I check the sum of years #5 and #6 which is 8 (>0). My expected output is "year 4".

---

What I did until now:

- I can find identify the first year with `area >0`:

  ```
  firstYear<-min(df$year[df$area > 0])
  ```
- And calculate the sum of the `area` of two following years:

  ```
  sum.year = sum(subset(df, year == firstYear + 1 | year == firstYear + 2)$area)
  ```

What I am not sure, is how to include the `if..else` or `while` statements to move to another `year` if the sum of the two following years  = 0?

I tried the `if..else` statement

```
if (sum.year >0) {
    print(firstYear)
  } else firstYear = firstYear + 1 # move and check the next year
```

but I think I need to include the `while` loop to move throughout my records:

```
while (firstYear <= max(df$year)) {
  if (sum.year >0) {
    print(firstYear)
  } else firstYear = firstYear + 1
}
```

But I can not figure out how to put if..else and while statements together? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you please provide your expected output? Do you simply want to mark such rows? Is this to be done by zone?

Comment: Thank you  @CalumYou, I have added my expected output. it is "4", meaning that first year with two following non zero years is year 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shift` to put the three values together on one row, and then test the condition:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

w = df[, shift(area, 0:2, type="lead")][V1 > 0 & V2 + V3 > 0, which=TRUE][1]

df[w]
#    year area
# 1:    4    8
```

In base R, maybe this is analogous (...I'm not sure):

```
m = embed(df$area, 3)
w = which(m[, 1] > 0 & m[, 2] + m[, 3] > 0)[1]
df[w, ]

#   year area
# 4    4    8
```

Comment: Wow @Frank. You just have opened for me an amazing space of time series analysis... I had no idea.. Thank you so much! I've tried both examples and both seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say area in year 6 is 8, I am assuming you are aggregating by year. By that logic the correct answer is year 2 (year 3 area = 0 and year 4 area = 8). Here's the code to do this using `lead` function from `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(#loc = rep(c("a"),each = 14),
               zone = rep(c("a", "b"), 7),
               year = rep(c(1:7),each= 2),
               area = c(0,1,
                        0,0,
                        0,0,
                        3,5,
                        0,0,
                        1,7,
                        2,2))
x <- group_by(df, year) %>% summarize(area = sum(area))
min(which(lead(x$area, 1, 0) > 0), which(lead(x$area, 2, 0) > 0))
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Shree. I am looking for the first year with area >0, that has area >0 up to two consecutive years. Therefore, it is year 4 (as year 2, in your example has 0). Do you know how to adapt your code for this?